# iOS - OAuth 2.0 How to fetch one-time code?

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, google-oauth

How can I get this one-time code ? I need this to enable server-side API access for my app.

I am using `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch`:

```
- (id)initWithScope:(NSString *)scope
           clientID:(NSString *)clientID
       clientSecret:(NSString *)clientSecret
   keychainItemName:(NSString *)keychainItemName
  completionHandler:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerCompletionHandler)handler
```

and completion handler is returning `completionHandler:^(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController, GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth, NSError *error)`

But one-time code is missing here.

Also as per initializer we have to pass scope, client id but Client ID for native application is missing.

As per https://console.developers.google.com/project/velvety-citizen-760/apiui/credential
I have enabled both Client ID for iOS application and Client ID for native application.

**My only main goal is to fetch one-time code as per diagram**

[image]